# wpf data validation control template - Not getting reflected when used on multiple pages

Tags: wpf, validation

I am trying to use wpf data validation as shown in link below.
[In WPF, How to display validation error in TextBox like the image below?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147894/in-wpf-how-to-display-validation-error-in-textbox-like-the-image-below)
The problem that I am facing is, I have a Title text box on first and last page of my application.
For both the pages viewmodel used is same and both the controls are bound to same property. I applied control template to both of them as shown, but somehow that validation part gets applied to only first text box, when I go to last page I cannot see the error on validation. It is default textbox without any validation shown on it. My validation is simple textbox empty validation.

Also when I comeback from last page to first page my control template validation is gone from first page also.
Textbox that I am using is from WPF.Extended.Toolkit.dll (WatermarkTextBox)
Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Are you using `IDataErrorInfo`? Some source code could be helpful!

Comment: Yes i am using IDataErrorInfo. Problem is solved from the below reply. But thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to wrap your textbox or the container with your textbox in a **AdornerDecorator** element.

```
<UserControl>
 <AdornerDecorator>
  <Grid>
   <TextBox/>
  </Grid>
 </AdornerDecorator>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Hi blindmeis, your solution worked. Thanks for that. But can you please explain what is the problem and how this solves the problem? I am just wondering do i need to surround each of the control to make it work or I can just keep it at page level or may be window level?